# RegEx for Number and Dash/Hyphen with Certain Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How to write JQuery/JavaScript RegEx pattern to allow only 3 numbers, 1 dash and 5 numbers OR 8 numbers?

`###-#####` or `########` (NO Space, NO More, NO Less and ONLY number with one dash/hyphen)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There's also a whitespace in the first example... please show at least some efforts, expected inputs and ouputs.

Answer (score 1):

Use .match or whatever, depending on your use case, with regex

```
^(\d{3}-\d{5})|\d{8}$
```

Answer (score 0):

regexPattern="[0-9]{3}[0-9-][0-9]{4}";

or 
"\d{3}[\d-]\d{4}"

Answer (score 0):

This conforms to your description:

```
\d{3}(\-)?\d{5}
```

And this to your example:

```
(\d \d{3}\-\d{5})|(\d{8})
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested working RegEx pattern

```
 var pattern = /^\(?\d{3}\)?[- ]?\d{5}$/;
 var val = inputs[i].value;
 if(!val.match(pattern)) {
   alert('Number and dash only(###-##### OR ########)');
          return false;
  }
```